# How to get statement_timeout for an existing connection/pid?

Tags: postgresql

Given a connection PID obtained by `select * from pg_stat_activity;`, how do I get value of `statement_timeout` set for that specific connection/PID?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I now there is no supported way of viewing another process's internal state like that.  But you could attach to the process with `gdb -p <pid>`, and get the timeout in ms by running:

```
print StatementTimeout
```

You will probably need to have the debug symbols installed to do that.